# Dedupe rule for organization always firing on membership signup form

Tags: civimember, duplicate-contacts

Our unsupervised rule for organizations is Organization name with a weight of 10 and the Postal Code length of 3 with a weight of 10 and a weight threshold of 20. We wanted to test behavior on a Membership signup form with the 'On behalf of my organization' option. For the organization data section, we entered different organizations with the same organization name but different postal codes first 3 characters and different emails. Everytime the organization data was updated. We thought it was supposed to recognize they were separate organizations create new records but it didn't.

We looked around and listened many times to the Civiteacher tutorials on dupes but it looks we are missing something.

In our project we have teachers buying reading clubs memberships for their classes on behalf of a school. It does occur that accross Canada we have different schools with the same name, but their postal code will differ. In that case we want to have different organization records created when people use the membership sign up form.

Are there references around that could explain what we are not understanding well or doing wrong?

Using CiviCRM 4.7.1 with Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@benoit.dubuc can you please test by applying patch from https://github.com/JMAConsulting/civicrm-core/commit/2eeb15fc142355f6e64e3b156f3e78e2e252b37e

Comment: Will check that today and try adding organisation with the dedupe rule posted in the original message.

Comment: We tested the patch with the scenario written about and I confirm the problem is now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

@benoit.dubuc as discussed on phone you've identified a bug. I've replicated this and created an issue for it https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18163. Thanks for offering to fund fixing it and creating an automated test to ensure it doesn't reappear.